# d3 click and drag event nesting

Tags: javascript, events, svg, d3.js

I am nesting a lot of elements inside of a g element like so:

```
<g>
    <rect></rect>
    <text></text>
    ...
</g>
```

However, there are some rects that I want to be able to have drag events of their own. The problem is that when you put stuff inside of a g tag, its size expands to contain those tags. So even though I can assign events there is no way they can be triggered because the g tag's event is somehow more important even though the rect is on top of it.

Is there some sort of workaround that you guys know of?

EDIT: Here's [a simple complete case](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrCQE/) in its entirety. A rect and a circle inside a g. The g is draggable and the circle should be draggable too but is not.

```
var gDragBehav = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', gDragDrag)

function gDragDrag(d,i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this)
        .attr('x', d.x)
        .attr('y', d.y)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
}

var circleDragBehav = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', circleDragDrag);

function circleDragDrag(d,i) {
    console.log('dragging a circle')
    d.cx += d3.event.dx;
    d.cy += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this)
        .attr('cx', d.cx)
        .attr('cy', d.cy)
}

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')

var g = svg.selectAll('g').data([{x: 10, y:10}])
    .enter().append('g').call( gDragBehav )

g.append( 'rect' ).attr('width', 100 ).attr('height', 100 )

g.selectAll( 'circle' ).data([{cx: 0, cy:0}])
    .enter().append( 'circle' )
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.cx } ).attr('cy', function(d) { return d.cy } )
    .attr('r', 40 )
    .call( circleDragBehav )
```

EDIT: Here's some of the code

```
var group = this.d3svg.selectAll('g' + '.' + this.className)
  .attr('x', this.drawFuncs['x'] )
  .attr('y', this.drawFuncs['y'] )
  .attr("transform", this.drawFuncs['translate'] )
  .attr('class', this.className )
  .call(gDragBehav)
  .on( 'click', blockClickMenu )

ports = ['AtomicPort']
for ( port in ports ) {  
  drawPort.call( this, group, ports[port] )
}

function drawPort( d3svg, portName, redraw ) {
  d3svg.selectAll('rect.' + portName)
    .data( function(d) { return d.ports[ portName ] } )
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', this.drawFuncs['x'] )
    .attr('y', this.drawFuncs['y'] )
    .attr('width', this.drawFuncs['width'] )
    .attr('height', this.drawFuncs['height'] )
    .attr('class', portName )
    .call(portDragBehav)

  var portDragBehav = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('drag', portDragDrag);

  function portDragDrag(d,i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('x', d.x)
      .attr('y', d.y)
    d3.event.stopPropagation();
  }

  var gDragBehav = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on('dragstart', gDragStart)

  function gDragDrag(d,i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('x', d.x)
      .attr('y', d.y)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
    d3.event.stopPropagation(); //Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stopPropagation'
  }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An SVG `<g>` element does not have a size or area; it is a transparent container for all its descendants, and cannot intercept events for other elements (unless you are adding an event listener to be triggered during the 'capture phase').

As a parent element, events bubble up to it; likely what you are seeing is that whatever event you're using to trigger the drag start (mousedown?) on the `<rect>` is also bubbling up to the `<g>` and starting a concurrent drag of *that*.

To fix this, you want to stop your event from bubbling. In your event handler for the mousedown (or whatever) on the `<rect>` add:

```
function startDrag(evt){
  // whatever your code is here
  evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

*Without your actual code (or better, a pared-down test case) it's hard to know for sure, or help you further.*

---

**Edit** Here's a working version of your simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrCQE/2/

Specifically, apparently `d3.event` is not the event itself, but an object with a `sourceEvent` property that references the actual event.

```
var dragGroup = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('dragstart', function() {
    console.log('Start Dragging Group');
  }).on('drag', function(d, i) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")");
  });

var dragCircle = d3.behavior.drag()
  .on('dragstart', function(){
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Start Dragging Circle');
  })
  .on('drag', function(d,i){
    d.cx += d3.event.dx;
    d.cy += d3.event.dy;
    d3.select(this).attr('cx', d.cx).attr('cy', d.cy)
  });

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('viewBox','-50 -50 300 300');

var g = svg.selectAll('g').data([{x:10,y:10}])
  .enter().append('g').call(dragGroup);

g.append('rect').attr('width', 100).attr('height', 100);

g.selectAll('circle').data([{cx: 90,cy:80}])
  .enter().append('circle')
    .attr('cx', function(d){ return d.cx })
    .attr('cy', function(d){ return d.cy })
    .attr('r', 30)
    .call(dragCircle);​
```

Comment: I am attaching the drag behavior to the g element itself, so that everything in the g's body will move. The problem is that the elements inside of the g tag weren't being called at all.

I'm not sure what you though is the problem but I do not have a handle on the event. How can I call stopPropagation?

Comment: @ballaw That's good (but expected) information. It does not change my answer.

Comment: OK, but I do not have a handle on the event. How can I call stopPropagation?

Comment: @ballaw I cannot help you without seeing your event registrations on the `<g>` and `<rect>`.

Comment: _"The problem is that the elements inside of the g tag weren't being called at all."_ I do not know what this sentence means. Particularly, what do you mean by "called"?

Comment: Whoops. I mean the events, not the elements. I posted some more code. There is a block that is draggable and inside of it there are smaller draggable blocks.

Comment: I added stopPropagation at the end of both drag behaviors but to no avail. The problem is that the nested port drag behavior is never called, not that it's propagating. I added console.log inside the port drag and it never prints anything.

Comment: @ballaw Sorry, I've reached my limit on this with only tiny glimpses into your code. Create a simple, pared-down, reproducible test case with minimal data and code and I might renew my efforts.

Comment: Wait, d3.event can't call stopPropagation. I get an error. I guess it is a different kind of event.

Comment: @ballaw Winner! That's what was needed. See my edit and working example. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar sort of issue (http://jsfiddle.net/j8RZN/1/), except the suggested workaround does not seem to be helping.

```
userBox.data([userBox]).call(d3.behavior.drag() //makes the box to move
//titleBox.data([userBox]).call(d3.behavior.drag()  //does not make the box move
.on("dragstart", function() {})
.on("drag", function(d, i) {
console.log('box being dragged');
d.attr("transform", "translate(" + (d3.event.x) +  "," + (d3.event.y) + ")");
})
.on("dragend", function() {}));

circleDrag.call(d3.behavior.drag()
.on("dragstart", function() {})
.on("drag", function(d, i) {
 d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
 console.log('small rectangle being dragged');
})
.on("dragend", function() {}));
```

Comment: d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); needs to go on 'dragStart' not 'drag'