# How do I translate a set of svg elements under a g when dragging?

Tags: svg, d3.js, transform

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Umugb/19/

I've written the code below to drag a set of elements around on an svg. Each `g` element has a `circle` that is draggable (but otherwise nothing else is). However, when I drag the circle, I'd like for the rest of the `g` to translate with it.

The problem is that the dragging goes haywire. If I take out the transform and instead just change the `circle`'s cx and cy to the new_cx and new_cy, then the circle is movable as expected. However, using transform, all of the elements fly off the page with d3.event.dx/dy of abnormally large absolute values.

Is there anything obviously wrong with the code below? Or does anyone have further insight into why this is happening?

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", translate);
function translate() {
    var g = $("#" + this.parentNode.id);
    var circle = d3.select(this);
    var r  = parseInt(circle.attr("r"));
    var box_width =  Math.max(g[0].getElementsByClassName('circletext')[0].getBBox().width, 2*r);

    var cx = parseInt(circle.attr("cx"));
    var cy = parseInt(circle.attr("cy"));
    if (g.attr("transform")) {
        var translate = g.attr("transform").split('translate')[1].split(',');
        cx = cx + parseInt(translate[0].slice(1));
        cy = cy + parseInt(translate[1].slice(0,-1));
    }

    var new_cx = Math.max(r, Math.min(width - box_width + r, d3.event.dx + cx));
    var new_cy = Math.max(r, Math.min(height - r, d3.event.dy + cy));
    d3.select("#" + this.parentNode.id).
        attr("transform",
             "translate(" + (new_cx-cx) + "," + (new_cy-cy) + ")");
```

EDIT: Updated with JSFiddle at top

Comment: Can you post a working example in jsFiddle?

Comment: Posted. Thanks for the reminder @PabloNavarro.

Comment: Perhaps this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095979/d3-click-and-drag-event-nesting) may help. Note: the jsfiddle works, just have to edit the d3.min.js link

Comment: I'll look at the linked answer a bit later when I'm home ... what do you mean though that the fiddle works? I'm looking at it right now with D3 3.0.4 loaded on the left and it's not working.