# d3 zoom, how to prevent target element click event

Tags: d3.js

I add zoom for my d3 map, but the map path has click event, so how to prevent event propagation when I'm zooming or draging by zoom component. I don't want to trigger the click event

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095979/d3-click-and-drag-event-nesting